# make nodeos use mongod.conf to change dbpath

Tags: nodeos, database

Currently when trying to use the mongodb plugin, I get this error

```
2018-10-11T15:47:15.635 thread-0   mongo_db_plugin.cpp:513       handle_mongo_excepti ] mongo exception, mongo init, line 1391, code 15, generic server error
```

It did work before, but then I did a few tweaks here and there to change the dbpath to save the db on the other HDD.

I figured out, when I run solely `mongo` in the terminal, I get the a related error --> `Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused`

When I run mongod (daemon) --> `ERROR: dbpath (/data/db) does not exist.
 Create this directory or give existing directory in --dbpath.`

In case I run `mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf`, to use the adjusted config file with specific dbpath, everything works as expected. `mongo` afterwards as well

When starting nodeos it seems to use the old dbpath and NOT dbpath from `/etc/mongod.conf` and `/etc/mongo.conf`, although I ran mongod before with the right path.

The question is how can I make nodeos use `mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf`? Or how can I change this globally ?

Running Ubuntu 16.04 on DigitalOcean and eos 1.3 with the following config.ini

```
http-server-address = 0.0.0.0:8888
p2p-listen-endpoint = 0.0.0.0:9876
bnet-endpoint = 0.0.0.0:4321

blocks-dir = "/mnt/volume_lon1_01/blocks"

bnet-follow-irreversible = 0
bnet-no-trx = false
bnet-peer-log-format = ["${_name}" ${_ip}:${_port}]
read-mode = read-only
validation-mode = light
mongodb-uri = mongodb://localhost:27017/EOS
mongodb-queue-size = 2048
mongodb-abi-cache-size = 2048
mongodb-block-start = 1
mongodb-store-transactions = 1
mongodb-store-transaction-traces = 1
mongodb-store-action-traces = 1
mongodb-filter-on = *
mongodb-filter-out = eosio:onblock:
mongodb-filter-out = gu2tembqgage::
mongodb-filter-out = blocktwitter::

wasm-runtime = wabt
p2p-max-nodes-per-host = 1
http-validate-host = false
https-client-validate-peers = 1
abi-serializer-max-time-ms = 5000
chain-state-db-size-mb = 32000
reversible-blocks-db-size-mb = 340
contracts-console = false
allowed-connection = any
max-clients = 100
network-version-match = 0
sync-fetch-span = 500
connection-cleanup-period = 30
max-implicit-request = 1500

access-control-allow-origin = *
access-control-allow-headers = *
access-control-allow-credentials = false
verbose-http-errors = true

plugin = eosio::chain_plugin
plugin = eosio::chain_api_plugin
plugin = eosio::bnet_plugin
plugin = eosio::http_plugin
plugin = eosio::mongo_db_plugin
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, with the help of a marameter, you performed file system manipulations, in particular with a block base, what exactly did you do?

check config.ini

datadir=  blocks-dir = "/mnt/volume_lon1_01/blocks"

Maybe your base has a different name already, for example

blocks-dir = "/mnt/volume_lon1_01/blocks_april12-10-2018"

Comment: the config.ini points always to the same path I think that's not the problem. It's probably EOS not calling mongo with the right & updated dbpath